# .NET is installed but not being detected

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have an app that targets .NET 3.5, but it isn't playing ball.

.NET 3.5, 3.0 and 2.0 are turned on in the control panel (Windows 8), and the Registry Editor shows that it is installed, but if I set an app to target vv3.5 I get this error -

> This application requires one of the following version of the .NET Framework: v3.5

Curiously, I notice that if I change the targeting to v3.5 via the properties (instead of manually editing `App.config`), the config changes to say that `v2.0.50727` is targeted -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Has anyone come across an issue like this before?

Comment: .NET Framework v3.0 and v3.5 are just extra libraries. They use the underlying runtime (CLR) v2.0. This is why `<supportedRuntime>` refers to v2.0.50727.

Comment: Ok, thanks. With that, could you possibly take a look at another question of mine, which I now believe may also be a .NET issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632896/outputting-to-excel-generates-an-exception-system-badimageformatexception

Comment: Please Check in your GAC Microsoft.Build.Framework has version 3.5.